# Need help with subgroup check.

Tags: group-theory

Suppose H is non empty subset of group G, that is closed group operation and has property that that if a is not in H (a^-1) is not in H. Is H a subgroup?

Don't know how to start..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $H$ is a subset of $G$ and is closed under the group operation, you just need to show that every element of $H$ has an inverse.  Suppose $b \in H$, and suppose $b^{-1} \not \in H$: then, however, calling $a = b^{-1}$, you have an element $a \not \in H$ and therefore $a^{-1} = b \not \in H$: this however is in contradiction with our hypothesis $b \in H$.

Comment: Thanks Marco..How to know when to use contradiction to prove? I was trying without contradiction, was unable to get anywhere..

Comment: You try and see if it works... :-) In your case, having a number of negative propositions, it is quite natural to try contradiction.